# HighCharts Column Chart: Data Labels on Stacks Overlap

Tags: highcharts, overlap, label

I have a column  chart in HighCharts and having issues where data labels are running into each other.  The graph has a static width and I could potentially have 4 series with at most 4 data points inside each series (4 stacks next to each other).  I do have positive and negative values.  I am seeing that if the series have similar values, each column is then the same height which causes the data labels to run into each other.

Any way to fix this issue? I cannot seem to find an library option that will help.

[image: Sample HighChart Column Chart - Data Label Overlap]

Comment: Can you post your chart config or a jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 2):

Added the groupPadding option worked for me:

```
plotOptions: 
{ 
    column: 
    { 
        dataLabels: 
        { 
            enabled: true, 
            formatter: function() { return this.y + '%' }
        } 
    }, 
    series: 
    {
        groupPadding: 0.125
    } 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the width of the bars? What about adjusting the font size of the labels? A combination of these 2 APIs should help get around this given you have a static sized chart and a maximum of 4 series with 4 data points...

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style

Comment: I started to play around with the groupPadding options which seems to be helping a little bit.  Setting the column point width does not work in very case because sometimes I do not have a lot of data and therefore, do not want to limit the size if not necessary  plotOptions: { series: {groupPadding: 0.25} }